# Docker: Set container name inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way that I can set what the containers name will be from inside the Dockerfile? Basically I want to always have the same name so I won't have to run "$docker ps" after building and running an image to get its name.

Answer (score 56):

The `Dockerfile` is for creating images not containers.

You can now give names to your containers using the new `--name` flag for `docker run`.

If `--name` is not provided Docker will automatically generate an alphanumeric string for the container name.

Comment: My upvote goes to this answer since it clearly point out the actual confusion between container and image of the question. 
That said, if you want to automate that **container** name then, this is still possible in a [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container-name) way

Comment: all very true though it is also possible to tag the image in the build phase: `docker build  -t tagname` in the 'name:tag' format which in turn can be used to `docker run tagname'

Answer (score 7):

From docker-compose.yml you can create a container and name it, you use:

```
container_name:
```

See this example:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - grafana-volume:/var/lib/grafana
```

If you don't use Docker compose you can use --name from the command line like this:

```
docker run --name=grafana
```

Comment: The question was about Dockerfile, you are describing how to do this in a docker compose file which is not an answer to the question. Though it could be helpful for someone if they are new to Docker it is still not really an answer to the question.  Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Alex you're completly right! I edit my post because I feel that it throws a little light to the whole discussion, and doing so it's clearer also for me... Thanks for your correct observation!

Comment: It didn't answer the question, but it was a timely reminder to myself to stop being silly running docker manually when I have docker-compose to do it for me.

Comment: In fact I wrote "If you don't use Docker compose"... go ahead til the end, next time

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason you need to define it in the dockerfile and not just name your containers when you run them?

If you are using docker run to run your images, then specify the name in the command line:

```
--name=""                     Assign a name to the container
```

[Docker Run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: Yes so you don't have to set the name everytime you run them and is defined the same for everyone eg in a dev tem

Answer (score 2):

I am adding another option based on [emoxxx's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798006/5493931). You could wrap a very simple docker-compose.yml around your existing Dockerfile to name the container. So, you keep your existing Dockerfile as is and just call it from a new and very basic docker-compose.yml file to get the container_name configuration option.

Create a new docker-compose.yml file in the same folder where the existing Dockerfile is. The new docker-compose.yml could look something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  myservice:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: 'the_new_container_name'
```

and then you just run it with:

```
docker-compose up
```

instead of the docker run. It will still do all the things you configured in your Dockerfile.